# Symbol meaning in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have attached a screen and highlighted the folder symbol (pict -1).
I want to know what does it mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a source control system (such as SVN or CVS) and you have deleted a folder. The folder will not actually be deleted until you commit your changes. The X shows you that the delete is pending.

Comment: Hi,I am using SVN. I have just renamed the folder from pict to bb. Does it mean pict copy still remains there in SVN(and not deleted)?

Comment: It will remain until your commit your changes.